# Unificar una columna de Fechas y otra de horas, Python

Tags: python

soy nuevo en Python y la programación y tengo que unir una columna de fechas y horas. La columna de horas, tiene varios espacios vacíos(NaN). Por Python solo e logrado unir las fechas con horas pero no traspasar las fechas que están solas.
[image: Tabla ejemplo de los datos]

El codigo que estoy haciendo es:

```
`import pandas as pd

df=pd.read_excel("PFH.xlsx")

print("Punto= ", df["Punto"].dtype)
print("Fecha= ", df["Fecha"].dtype)
print("Hora= ", df["Hora"].dtype)
df['Hora'].fillna(0)
print("------------------------------------------")
df['Fecha'] = df['Fecha'].astype(str)
print("Fecha= ", df["Fecha"].dtype)
print("------------------------------------------")

df['Fecha y hora']= df['Fecha'] + ' ' + df['Hora']`
```

pienso hacer algun ciclo o función para llenar esos espacios vacios pero no e podido.

Comment: para llenar la salida de un dataframe con valores vacios puedes hacer `df.fillna(tu_valor_de_relleno_aqui)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buen día,

Al rellenar los valores en lugar de rellenarlos con 0, los puedes rellenar con un `sring` vacío `''`.

Luego únicamente concatenas la fecha y la hora tal como lo has hecho en la última línea de código que pusiste en tu pregunta

Y para eliminar el espacio en blanco de las filas que únicamente tienen fecha puedes utilizar el método `rstrip()`

Como no pusiste tus datos en formato de texto inventé unos cuantos datos (Esto está en el archivo sample2.csv del ejemplo)

```
    Fecha       Hora
0   1992-11-11  14:20:00
1   1992-11-19  NaN
2   1992-11-28  NaN
3   1992-11-28  NaN
4   1992-11-29  NaN
5   1992-11-30  NaN
6   1992-11-30  NaN
```

Ejemplo aplicando los comentarios anteriores:

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.read_csv('sample2.csv')
df['Hora'] = df['Hora'].fillna('')
df['Fecha y Hora'] = df['Fecha'] + ' ' + df['Hora']
df['Fecha y Hora'] = df['Fecha y Hora'].str.rstrip()
```

Esto crea el siguiente `dataframe`:

```
    Fecha       Hora        Fecha y Hora
0   1992-11-11  14:20:00    1992-11-11 14:20:00
1   1992-11-19              1992-11-19
2   1992-11-28              1992-11-28
3   1992-11-28              1992-11-28
4   1992-11-29              1992-11-29
5   1992-11-30              1992-11-30
6   1992-11-30              1992-11-30
```

Comment: Muchísimas gracias @HeytalePazguato